# Is it possible ro change the floating action button label to right of icon

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button, floating-action-menu

I am using  [Clans FloatingActionButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3xwt.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3xwt.png): https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton. By default the layout appears as [image: this] The Label for button is in the left and button to right. Is it possible to change the layout as, button to the left and label to the right of button

Comment: Have you tried `fab:menu_labels_position`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the lib you are using :

You can find the option like :

fab:menu_labels_position="right"

and

FloatingActionButton set it to left in layout

so you can change according your need .

Answer (score 0):

In the git project https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton
search for  **' fab:menu_labels_position="left" '** 
and edit it to **' fab:menu_labels_position="right" '**.
Hope you got the answer. :)